Geometry node - Noise texture on curve with height mask
I have a geometry node setup with a curve with noise texture applied on it to get random noise. Currently the noise is applied equally on the curve geometry. Is there a way to mask out the noise at the bottom and gradually increase towards top? I thought about creating a height mask, but not sure how to do it on this setup.

Capture the Factor from your curve and multiply or divide by that as desired?
